# Are there any sites that review front covers and give you feedback?

Tags: drawing, art

I am making a game front cover and I have made a front cover for it but it isnt that good and I am not sure what other people would think either. Is there a site (it could be this one) that I can upload a front cover and ask for feedback and for suggested others were i give a brief description of my game and it goes from there?

Comment: Sure, you can ask here if you follow the [critique guidelines](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/682). This question is too broad for this site as it's a shopping request though.

Comment: ok I will look into it